# To look + adjective/adverb

Tags: grammar

Normally, you use adjectives for describing the way someone looks, e.g.: "He looks good".
Following this logic, it should be: "You look shit". However, in a movie, someone said: "You look shitty".
Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. "Shitty" is an adjective. See https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/shitty